# Stop a looping function when one value is greater than another within loop

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I have been trying to write a `while` command to stop the looping function when one value generated by the loop exceeds the other. However, I have failed to figure out the proper way to do it.

The `for` loop runs for 30 days, but I want it to stop as soon as the last value of `parasite_l.A` is less than than `parasite_l.B`.

I have included the working code I have for generating the data and the for loop.

Alternative solutions without a limit on the loop would also be greatly appreciated.

```
# Subject A, initially 400 parasites, growing by 10 %
subA = 400
infA = 1.1

# Subject B, initially 120 parasites, growing by 20 %
subB = 120
infB = 1.2

# How many days to model
days = 30

days_seq = seq(1, days, 1)

# Parasite load for A
parasite_l.A = rep(NA, days)
parasite_l.A[1] = subA

# Parasite load for B
parasite_l.B = rep(NA, days)
parasite_l.B[1] = subB

# Loop for subject A and B
for(i in 1:(days)){
    parasite_l.A[i+1] = parasite_l.A[i]*(infA)
    parasite_l.B[i+1] = parasite_l.B[i]*(infB)
  }

parasite_l.A
parasite_l.B
```

Comment: "The for loop runs for 30 days" - might be worth considering a different, more efficient approach than your existing for loop. Just as a side note

Comment: As a side note, `parasite_l.A` can be created with `subA * (infA ^ (0:days))`; though in this case, many not needed values will be computed since there can't be a "break" condition before the computation.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative @alexis_laz! That is far more efficient for generating the values I want within a timespan.

Comment: You say, "The for loop runs for 30 days, but I want it to stop as soon as the last value of parasite_l.A is greater than parasite_l.B.". But you mean "less than" or else the function would stop on the first value. A = 400; B = 120

Comment: @PierreLafortune. Thanks for catching the error. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in control flow function for what you are referring to named `while`. As long as the conditions are met it will continue to loop.

```
i <- 1    
while (parasite_l.A[i] > parasite_l.B[i]) {
      parasite_l.A[i+1] = parasite_l.A[i]*(infA)
    parasite_l.B[i+1] = parasite_l.B[i]*(infB)
    i <- i + 1
}

# parasite_l.A
#  [1]  400.0000  440.0000  484.0000  532.4000  585.6400  644.2040  708.6244
#  [8]  779.4868  857.4355  943.1791 1037.4970 1141.2467 1255.3714 1380.9085
# [15] 1518.9993        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# [22]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# [29]        NA        NA
#  parasite_l.B
#  [1]  120.0000  144.0000  172.8000  207.3600  248.8320  298.5984  358.3181
#  [8]  429.9817  515.9780  619.1736  743.0084  891.6100 1069.9321 1283.9185
# [15] 1540.7022        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# [22]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# [29]        NA        NA
```

Comment: This won't work since you are using the vectors in the `condition` of the `while` loop. It's going to test the sum of A vs the sum of B.

Comment: @PaulJames It just needed the `i` in the condition. There is no problem with using vectors in the condition. And a side note, the OP was backwards in their description. They want up to B greater than A, not the other way around as described.

Comment: You're right, you can use a vector in the `while` loop, but I'm right in that it will sum the vector. When you reference an element in the vector with an index, you are using that specific element as the condition, not the entire vector.

Comment: @PaulJames That's not true either. It will not auto-sum. Try `c(1:5) <= 4`. The sum of the vector is never compared to the second. The second value is recycled.

Comment: Thanks @PierreLafortune for the solution, and for catching the error in my description, while figuring out what I actually wanted from my coding. That's just brilliant. I chose your code as the answer because it's more efficient than the one offered by PauiJames.

Answer (score 2):

Use an index value (`i`), a couple of counters (`A.index.value`, `B.index.value`), and a `while` loop:

```
# Subject A, initially 400 parasites, growing by 10 %
subA <- A.index.value <- 400
infA <- 1.1

# Subject B, initially 120 parasites, growing by 20 %
subB <- B.index.value <- 120
infB <- 1.2

# How many days to model
days <- 30

days_seq <- seq(1, days, 1)

# Parasite load for A
parasite_l.A <- rep(NA, days)
parasite_l.A[1] <- subA

# Parasite load for B
parasite_l.B <- rep(NA, days)
parasite_l.B[1] <- subB

# While Loop for subject A and B
i <- 1
while (A.index.value > B.index.value) {
    parasite_l.A[i+1] <- A.index.value <- parasite_l.A[i]*(infA)
    parasite_l.B[i+1] <- B.index.value <-  parasite_l.B[i]*(infB)
    i <- i + 1
}

parasite_l.A
parasite_l.B
```

With the results being:

```
> parasite_l.A
 [1]  400.00  440.00  484.00  532.40  585.64  644.20  708.62  779.49  857.44 943.18 1037.50
[12] 1141.25 1255.37 1380.91 1519.00      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
[23]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
> parasite_l.B
 [1]  120.00  144.00  172.80  207.36  248.83  298.60  358.32  429.98  515.98  619.17  743.01
[12]  891.61 1069.93 1283.92 1540.70      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
[23]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about the possibility of using counters in R. It solves the problem, I just marked Pierre's solution because it was a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (parasite_l.A < parasite_l.B) { // if parasite a is less than b, do the following // 
    for(i in 1:(days)){
       parasite_l.A[i+1] = parasite_l.A[i]*(infA)
       parasite_l.B[i+1] = parasite_l.B[i]*(infB)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inside the loop something like:

```
    if (parasite_l.A > parasite_l.B) {
      break
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if using a `for(...){...}` loop.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I realise I need to use the `break` statement with the condition. However, I must be writing my code incorrectly because I could not get it to work.

Comment: Did you put this statement inside your for loop with the index?

Comment: This was how I tried it `if (parasite_l.A < parasite_l.B) { 
    for(i in 1:(days)){
      parasite_l.A[i+1] = parasite_l.A[i]*(infA)
      parasite_l.B[i+1] = parasite_l.B[i]*(infB)
    } break
}`